# включении и отключение button пока не произошло событие

Tags: javascript, html

Суть такая, до того как пользователь нажал кнопку "рассчитать" остальные кнопки сделать неактивными (пусть даже нажимаются, но не производят ни каких логических операций). Для решения данной задачи добавил функцию getButton() и повесил ее  на события клика кнопки "Начать расчет" (не выполняет свою функцию) выносишь ее за вызов  отрабатывает странно, изначально кнопки не активны (все как и должно быть) но после нажатия они по прежнему не активны, не понимаю почему так?

```
let startBtn = document.getElementById("start"),
budgetValue = document.querySelector(".budget-value"),
dayBudgetValue = document.getElementsByClassName('daybudget-value')[0],
lavelValue = document.getElementsByClassName('level-value')[0],
expensesValue = document.getElementsByClassName('expenses-value')[0],
optionalExpensesValue = document.getElementsByClassName('optionalexpenses-value')[0],
incomeValue = document.getElementsByClassName('income-value')[0],
monthSavingsValue = document.getElementsByClassName("monthsavings-value")[0],
yearSavingsValue = document.getElementsByClassName("yearsavings-value")[0],

expensesItem = document.getElementsByClassName("expenses-item"),
expensesBtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]/* это кнопка складывает обязатльенве расходы */ ,
optionalExpensesBtn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[1]/*передает не обязателоные траты */,
countBtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[2]/*расчет дневного бюджета */,
optionalExpensesItem = document.querySelectorAll(".optionalexpenses-item"),
chooseIncome = document.querySelector(".choose-income"),
checkSavings = document.querySelector(".checksavings"),
sumValue = document.querySelector('.choose-sum'),
percentValue = document.querySelector (".choose-percent" ),
yearValue = document.querySelector(".year-value"),
monthValue = document.querySelector(".month-value"),
dayValue = document.querySelector(".day-value");


let money, time;


function getButton(){ 
    if (startBtn.onclick == true){ 
        expensesBtn.disabled = false; 
        optionalExpensesBtn.disabled = false; 
        countBtn.disabled = false; 
    } else { 
        expensesBtn.disabled = true; 
        optionalExpensesBtn.disabled = true; 
        countBtn.disabled = true; 
    }  
}; 
getButton();

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    time = prompt(' Введите дату в формате YYYY-MM-DD', '');
    money = +prompt(' Ваш бюджет в мясяц?', '');



    while (isNaN(money) || money == '' || money == null){
        money = prompt(' Ваш бюджет?', '');
    }
    appData.budget = money;
    appData.timeData = time;
    budgetValue.textContent = money.toFixed();
    yearValue.value = new Date(Date.parse(time)).getFullYear();
    monthValue.value = new Date(Date.parse(time)).getMonth() + 1;
    dayValue.value = new Date(Date.parse(time)).getDate();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поместите включение необходимых кнопок внутрь функции события:

```js
expensesBtn.disabled = true;
optionalExpensesBtn.disabled = true;
countBtn.disabled = true;

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

// Вот сюда

expensesBtn.disabled = false;
optionalExpensesBtn.disabled = false;
countBtn.disabled = false;
}
```

UPD: Вообще ваш скрипт отрабатывает логически верно. Вы объявили функцию **getButton()**, потом сразу же ее вызвали. Она тут же проверила все ваши условия и все выполнила. Закончила свое предназначение. Но клик по кнопке происходит не сразу после загрузки страницы, а в результате работы с ней. А ваша функция **getButton()** вызывается сразу после прогрузки страницы.

Именно поэтому я предлагаю засунуть включение/отключение кнопок в момент обработки события "*click*" по **startBtn**.

Comment: Можно добавить getButton(); в startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

Comment: @Роман, я бы вложил как простую логику, чтобы код был чище. А чтобы ничего не ломалось, при вкладывании функции, уберите из нее лишнее. Например, проверку. Незачем там проверка на клик, если функция и так вызывается при клике, верно?

Comment: я так понимаю только вот это if (startBtn.onclick == true){ 
        expensesBtn.disabled = false; 
        optionalExpensesBtn.disabled = false; 
        countBtn.disabled = false; 
    } else { 
        expensesBtn.disabled = true; 
        optionalExpensesBtn.disabled = true; 
        countBtn.disabled = true; 
    }

Comment: просто после добавление логики ломается другая функция ((( Просто если вложить как функцию то ломается вот это логика (она принимает от пользователя наименование товара и цену на него и собирает это это в сумму(массив kye: value) и предает в раздел "Обязательные расходы") поломка в том что при вводе числа предаветь  NaN

Comment: @Роман, я обновил код в ответе. Посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает. Оказывается я просто сделал лишнюю работу и все было проще чем кажется.